# Best way to handle response.status on fetch POST

Tags: javascript, rest, post, fetch

I've built a login panel, which will submit an email and password via `fetch/POST`.  And I wanted to know the best way to handle response.status errors?

Reason being, as I want to inject error messages into my login panel for each state/status code.

I've written the code below, which works.  But I wondered if there is a better way to write this?

```
let url = 'www.MYAPI.com/xyz';

// post body data
let data = {
    "Username": emailAddress,
    "Password": Password,
  }

// create request object
let request = new Request(url, {
    "method": 'POST',
    "mode": 'cors',
    "credentials": 'include',
    "body": JSON.stringify(data),
    "referrerPolicy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin",
    "headers": {
        "accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
        "content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
        "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
        "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
        "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest"
    }
});

fetch(request)
.then( async (response) => {
    let data = await response.json();

    if(response.status === 200){
     // LOGIN SUCCESSFUL HERE;
        console.log("Successful log in - status: ", data);
        document.getElementById("id01").style.display = "none"; // HIDE LOGIN PANEL
    } else{
     // Rest of status codes (400,500,303), can be handled here appropriately

        // IF EMAIL ADDRESS ERROR / STATUS 502
        if (data.KnownErrorDescription === "MemberEmailDoesNotExist") {
            document.getElementById("email-error").innerHTML = "Please enter a valid email address to sign in";
        };

        // IF PASSWORD IS EMPTY / STATUS 400
        if (data.Message === "The request is invalid.") {
            document.getElementById("password-error").innerHTML = data.ModelState["request.Password"][0];
        }

        // // IF ACCOUNT LOCKED / 502
        if (data.KnownErrorDescription === "MemberAccountLocked") {
            document.getElementById("failed-sign-in-error").innerHTML = "You need to reset your password";
            document.getElementById("password-reset").style.display = "block";
        }
    };

  })
  .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
  })
```

Comment: How confident are you in the responses that will be coming in?  [The `200`-`299` range is considered "successful responses"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status), so if you don't have control over the response status, you could do `if(response.status < 300)` or something like that.  Also, as this is code that is working that you just want additional eyes on, you _may_ consider posting to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ .  Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: @andrew I actually need to spend some more time handling all the network responses, but this was just for example :) And thank you for the recommendation, I will check out codereview.stackechange.